# Repartition in repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions happens on driver or on worker

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, datastax, partitioning

I am trying to understand the concept of `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` in Spark Streaming whether the repartition happens on driver or on worker. If suppose it happens on driver then does worker wait for all the data to come before sorting happens.

Answer (score 1):

Like any other transformation it is handled by executors. Data is not passed via the driver. In other words this standard shuffle mechanism and there is nothing streaming specific here.

Destination of each record is defined by:

- Its key.
- `Partitioner` used for a given shuffle.
- Number of partitions.

and data is passed directly between executor nodes.

From the comments it looks like you're more interested in a Spark Streaming architecture. If that's the case you should take a look at [Diving into Apache Spark Streaming’s Execution Model](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/30/diving-into-apache-spark-streamings-execution-model.html). To give you some overview there can exist two different types of streams:

- Receiver-based with a receiver node per stream.
- Direct (without receiver) where only metadata is assigned to executors but data is fetched directly.

Comment: I am using the  ReceiverInputDStream approach  as mentioned in this link.`https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-RabbitMQ/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/rabbitmq/receiver/RabbitMQInputDStream.scala`.  what's the flow in the second approach(`direct without receiver`) which you mentioned. I couldn't find any link relate to that.

Comment: For non trivial example see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers